# How can I set input type button holds different values

Tags: php, html

In the `while` loop I display the doctor name, specialist and payment. For each doctor I want to have a button to send him a message. Every doctor has an doctor id (did). But `<input type="hidden" name="did" value="<?php echo $row3['did'];?>"/>` it cannot hold the different values. What can I do to set different values using:

```
<input type="hidden" name="did" value="<?php echo $row3['did'];?>"/>
```

or:

```
<input type='button' name='contact' id='contact' value="Message" class='contact demo btn btn-primary'/>
```

Here is my code:

```
while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
{       
?>
    <div class="col_1_of_4 span_1_of_4">
        <div class="title-img">
        <div class="title">
            <img src="images/Crystal_Clear_user.gif" alt="">
        </div>                                      
        <div class="clear"></div> 
    </div>
    <h4 class=head>Doctor name: <?php echo $row3['dName'];?></h4>
    <p>Specialist: <?php echo $row3['specialist'];?></p>
    <p>Payment: <?php echo $row3['payment'];?></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="did" value="<?php echo $row3['did'];?>"/>

    <hr>                            
        <div id='contact-form'>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">more</a>

            <input type='button' name='contact' id='contact' value="Message" class='contact demo btn btn-primary'/>
        </div>

        <!-- preload the images -->
        <div style='display:none'>
            <img src='images/loading.gif' alt='' />
        </div>                  
    </div>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in order to store different values in same variable.

do it like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="did[]" value="<?php echo $row3['did'];?>">
```

changes:

```
name="did"
```

into

```
name="did[]"
```

the variable "did" should be array.

to view the data :

```
var_dump($_POST["did"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change button's value without affecting it's label. I'd suggest you to wrap every row's button into a separate form with a hidden field.

You should have 1 `<form>` tag per row. I believe simple:

```
<form method='post' action='/your-submit-script-goes-here.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='did' value='<?php echo $row3['did'];?>'>
    <input type='button' name='contact' id='contact' value="Message" class='contact demo btn btn-primary'/>
</form>
```

will do the trick.

Don't forget to remove your current `<form>` tags.

So your code will be as follows:

```
while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
{       
?>
    <div class="col_1_of_4 span_1_of_4">
        <div class="title-img">
        <div class="title">
            <img src="images/Crystal_Clear_user.gif" alt="">
        </div>                                      
        <div class="clear"></div> 
    </div>
    <h4 class=head>Doctor name: <?php echo $row3['dName'];?></h4>
    <p>Specialist: <?php echo $row3['specialist'];?></p>
    <p>Payment: <?php echo $row3['payment'];?></p>

    <hr>                            
        <div id='contact-form'>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">more</a>

            <form method='post' action='/your-submit-script-goes-here.php'>
                <input type='hidden' name='did' value='<?php echo $row3['did'];?>'>
                <input type='button' name='contact' value="Message" class='contact demo btn btn-primary'/>
            </form>
        </div>

        <!-- preload the images -->
        <div style='display:none'>
            <img src='images/loading.gif' alt='' />
        </div>                  
    </div>
<?php
}
```

Comment: i use array but  it only holds the first row value @kenn

Comment: it only hold the first row value.that means,if i press the button for the last doctor, it holds the first doctors did

Comment: Look for <form> tag definitions. You might have opened one <form> tag before the while() cycle and when you press the button it sends all the form fields. Can you show it somewhere on the web?